# Creating the stereo photosphere without Unity

Tags: google-vr, daydream

I'm working on a Daydream app using the Google VR SDK/NDK. To submit the app to Google Play, I need a 360-degree stereo photosphere. I've seen directions for creating this with Unity, but is there any way to create this without Unity?

I've taken a screenshot of the app in stereo mode, but I don't think that will satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't provide any tools to capture in-app photospheres in non-Unity apps at this time. Some devs produce photospheres in modeling apps like Maya and Blender.

Answer (score 0):

You could always cheat and make your "Daydream 360 degree stereoscopic image" in Photoshop. Just use the same image twice, once on top and once on the bottom.

I think others have already done this, because I have noticed a few wrong looking previews in the store. Where if I close one eye, parts of the image disappear.

If you change your mind and make one with Unity, this plugin worked nicely for me: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38755